# Как в peewee извлечь только дату, если сам столбец имеет формат DateTimeField()

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, peewee

[image: первый]

[image: второй]

В общем на первом скрине SQL запрос, который извлекает все даты и удаляет дубликаты даты, при этом первоначальный столбец имеет запись в формате DateTimeField(), т.е. в строковой переменной есть еще время (второй скрин). Отсекается время и выдаются даты без дубликатов.

Долго ломаю голову, не могу сделать то же самое в peewee. Есть вариант использовать функцию date так же, как мы используем ее в SQL? D документации написано, что можно извлекать отдельно день, месяц, год, но дату я е нашел...

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно воспроизвести запрос с помощью peewee, то в peewee есть модуль fn. И с помощью него вы можете вызывать функцию с любым именем.

```
from peewee import fn

Order.select(fn.DATE(Order.date)).distinct()

> ('SELECT DISTINCT DATE("t1"."date") FROM "order" AS "t1"', [])
```

`fn` позволяет писать какое угодно имя функции, хоть `fn.FOOBAR` (конечно тогда все упадет с `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: FOOBAR`)

Comment: Спасибо! Аналогичной функции в пиви похоже все таки нет, перерыл документацию, не нашел:(

Comment: @Егор Что значит аналогичной. Дело peewee - транслировать код на питоне в SQL, что она и делает. За базу данных она работу делать не будет. Если нужно преобразование типа свойства, то это уже конвертеры, но они работают после базы данных.